# 'RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found Xcode error

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I am looking to add the Apple Health-Kit to my React-Native project. After following the instructions for the installation here: https://github.com/terrillo/rn-apple-healthkit

I am given this error below.

[image]

I have tried to replace the line in the file causing the error from

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

to

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
```

But I still get the same error as before.

Comment: have you tried `cd ios` and then `pod install` ?

Comment: Yes I ran a pod install and still the same error appears.

Comment: clean build project (shift + option + command + k) and then try again to build.

Comment: Still getting the same error as before. I have tried it with #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h> and #import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

Comment: The version of React Native I am using is react-native: 0.61.2 is this too high for apple health kit?